# strip php timestamp from filename, if it exists

Tags: php, regex, timestamp, substring

I'm trying to retrieve the filename of an image by removing the timestamp added to it. An image may or may not have a timestamp attached to it. For example it may be in this format:

`mylogo.1358256757.jpg`

or it may simply be:

`mylogo.jpg`

It could be `jpg`, `png` or any other valid image file.

The timestamp was generated using:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();
```

I need a PHP regex that will retain the original image name, assuming:

- the image can have any possible filename, including as numbers and
  dots, and
- it may not have a timestamp at all!

I can use substrings etc I'm just wondering what the safest way would be to go about it. Will a PHP timestamp always be exactly 10 digits?

Comment: If the file has a timestamp, is the only possible format going to be as in your example (i.e. filename.timestamp.extension)?

Comment: "Always" is relative in this case, since it's a quantifier of seconds. In 2050 the timestamp would be 10 digits, `2524629600`, but in 3000 it would be 11 digits, `32503701600`.

Comment: Okay will I guess we can safely assume it'll remain 10 digits for the next 10 years then!

Comment: I asked only because, if this is the only format, you can merely remove the .timestamp and wouldn't necessarily need preg for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$filename = "mylogo.1358256757.jpg";
$filename = preg_replace('/^(.*)\.\d+\.(gif|jpg|png)$/', '$1.$2', $filename);
```

If you want to only consider a certain number of digits a timestamp, 8 for example, you just need to qualify the `\d`:

```
$filename = preg_replace('/^(.*)\.\d{8,}\.(gif|jpg|png)$/', '$1.$2', $filename);
//                                  ^^^^ 8 or more digits
```

You can also do some semantic checks to see if the suspected timestamp is in a certain window.  The following checks to make sure that the timestamp embedded in the filename represents a date/time in the last 1 year.  If it is, it does the replacement, and if not it just returns the original filename (this code requires PHP 5.3.0 or better):

```
$filename = "mylogo.1358256757.jpg";     

$filename = preg_replace_callback(
    '/^(.*)\.(\d+)\.(gif|jpg|png)$/',
    function ($matches) {
        $when = new DateTime();
        if ($when->setTimestamp(intval($matches[2])) !== false) {
            $start = new DateTime('1 year ago');
            $end   = new DateTime();

            // Is it a timestamp in the last year?
            if ($when > $start && $when < $end) {
                return $matches[1] . '.' . $matches[3];
            }
        }

        // Doesn't appear to be valid, return the original
        // filename.
        return $matches[0];
    },
    $filename);

echo $filename . "\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

If Regex is not mandatory, you could also split (explode for example) the filename up on the '.' (dots) and only use the first and third part, glue those back together to get a filename without the timestamp part.

The 'if exists' part of your question is (in its simplest form) a matter of examining the number of 'tokens' you got returned from the explode (or similar) function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_replace`

[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

You will get the file name by using this

```
$prevFileName = "mylogo.1358256757.jpg";
$fileName = preg_replace('/(\\.\\d+\\.)/', '.', $prevFileName);
echo $fileName;
```